# How to define the stored procedure input data types , to be based on other columns data types

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2 to perform an advanced search like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AdvanceSearch]
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
        @SearchType nvarchar(10) = null,
        @SerialNumber varchar(50) = null,
//code goes here
```

Currently the `@SerialNumber` variable represents a real column inside a table named `Assets`. The serial number column has a data type of `varchar(50)` and it allows null values.

So what I did is that i manually define the same datatype which is `varchar(50)`. But my question is what will happen if in the future I change the datatype for the `SerialNumber` column inside the `Assets` table, then I have to change the type in my stored procedure.

Is there a way to define the datatype for the `@SerialNumber` parameter inside the stored procedure to be the same as the datatype of a column inside another table? So that if the column type changes the stored procedure parameter will have the new datatype?

Thanks

Comment: No, something like that isn't possible in SQL Server. The types of stored procedure parameters **must** be declared completely and statically in the stored procedure declaration - they cannot be changed at runtime depending on the datatype of a column of some table

Comment: As @marc_s says, you can't do this in SQL Server. It is possible in Oracle which is possibly where you have seen this before.

Comment: Unfortunately, the feature that should make something similar to this work (user defined types - where you'd declare say a serial number type and then both the column and the parameter would be of that type instead) is horribly broken in SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own datatype based on a varchar, and use that as datatype for both the table and the stored procedure:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[serialNumber] FROM [varchar](50)

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AdvanceSearch]
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
        @SearchType nvarchar(10) = null,
        @SerialNumber [serialNumber] = null,
//code goes here
```

But I would not recommend going this way, due to the reasons the others have mentioned (there is no `ALTER TYPE`, and you will have to drop all referenced objects in order to change the type by doing drop/create).

In short: It's not possible, and the best option is to use a regular varchar, and use a tool like [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) to manually find and change everything if needed in the future.

Comment: You can, but of course you can't alter the type without having to rip the type out of all tables/procedures using it and then re-creating it with a new definition.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no `ALTER TYPE` command, so if you ever want to **change** that datatype, you'd have to first drop all the objects (including the `dbo.AdvanceSearch` stored procedure), drop the old type, create the new type, and then recreate everything. Unfortunately, this makes user-defined types pretty much useless in my opinion ....

Comment: I just realized this when i tried it out. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: so if i change the serialnumber data type insdie the Assets table to be for example nvarchar(100) instead of varchar(50). the i have to manully modify the SP and chnage the @SerialNumber to match the new datatype ?

Comment: @johnG: No, you will actually have to drop all tables/procedures using that datatype in order to change it, which is really bad :)